# Struts2 <s:checkbox> with 'value="true" not rendered as preselect if has Angular `ng-model`

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, struts2

I have observed a very peculiar behavior of `<s:checkbox>` rendering along with Bootstrap 3 and AngularJS.

I have these two `<s:checkbox>` in my page, wrapped by some elements of Bootstrap 3 styles:

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-other">
            <label for="activaCheck"><s:text name="actividad.busqueda.activa"/></label>
                <s:checkbox class="form-control" id="activaCheck" name="activaCheck" ng-model="formData.activaCheck" value="true"></s:checkbox>
                <s:checkbox class="form-control" id="activaCheck2" name="activaCheck2"  value="true"></s:checkbox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the only difference between them, is that the first has attribute `ng-model = "xxx"`, while the second doesn't.

And, in my page, they are rendered differently, although they both are supposed to be pre-selected, because I set `value="true"`. And when we inspect in FF, we can see **the first `<s:checkbox>` has `checked="checked"`, but is not rendered.** I have tested in Chrome and FF, same.

I have also tested with `<input type="checkbox" />` with `ng-model` set and `checked="checked"`, the same: not checked when rendered in page.

[image: The first checkbox is "checked", but not rendered.]

So I am thinking about AngularJS is taking over part of rendering job which Struts 2 is responsible of, at least in this case. I want some explanation from developers of AngularJS, or this is the expected result?

Comment: If it is angular controlled checkbox then pre-select it via model.

Comment: yup, continue with angular after the page is rendered and take the pre-checked value from Struts2 checkbox.

Comment: May I say that, if we put `ng-model` here, the checkbox is taken over by Angular? Or, Angular works post-Struts, so they may be inconsistent?

Comment: Struts tags are irrelevant in this case. You can use plain checkbox input with `checked="checked"` and still get the same result. Angular controls this input because of the `ng-model`.

Comment: Angular works on the client-side, Struts works on the server-side, but angular is not so perfect, as it seems at the ideology broadcasted over the community, and have also disadvantages that are also in comparing to advantages give zero effect.

Comment: So if we don't want any unpredictable behavior from Angular(uncheck checkboxes that should be checked), we must avoid setting `ng-model`, right? So we must learn from it that don't mix one thing with another.... but sometimes we have to.

Comment: Without ng-model you can't use angular's model object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem with unchecked checkbox. Because it has `ng-model` attribute the input control is bound to Angular's `$scope`. And if the scope doesn't define the property value for the above named checkbox it's not checked. Assumed that AngularJS modifies DOM as soon as it initializes.

I have created [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bXGaFAQFOYLF307XGoNt?p=preview) to demonstrate it.

You are right AngularJS starts working after document is loaded. At this time Struts has already done its work and returned html document to the browser. Now Angular continues to prepare the page to work only on one page. Both complement each other, but if Struts use to render

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value1" checked="checked">
```

Angular removes the checked state, because the value is commented

```
angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkboxModel = {
   //value1 : true,
   value2 : 'YES'
 };
}]);
```